# User privacy policy when visiting page on Amazon S3

Tags: privacy

I have a static webpage that advertises my mobile app for the App Store. The page is stored on an Amazons S3 bucket. It has no ads and doesn't use cookies. Do I still need a privacy policy, because I can't speak for Amazon, what happens with his meta data, since my page is sitting on their server.

Comment: You may want to clarify if you are asking about a certain jurisdiction, or list the jurisdictions you expect to do business in.  I assume your question is about GDPR, but that's not the only possible relevant law.